# HTML5 number spinbox controls not triggering a change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

We are currently using jQuery to trigger a recalculation on a form input field. Using HTML5 we get nice spinboxes in Safari (at least on 5.0.3 Mac). However updating the field with the spinbox controls doesn't seem to trigger a change event at all. It's like the field hasn't been updated. Is this just an oversight in WebKit? Or are there ways around this?

Edit: Changing the spinbox doesn't even trigger an input event.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `oninput` event.  Use something like `$("...").bind("input", fn);`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592978(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah, even with binding both input and change that was no dice. :/

Comment: Looks like the solution for now is to forego <input type="number"> and rather use <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]>, which produces the desired result in iOS and hopefully other mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

$.click() works fine. If you click and hold, it doesn't until you release.

Answer (score 0):

change event is triggered when input **lost focus** and the value is changed, by clicking the spinbox, input does not lost its focus, so change event will not fired.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense in explaining why (even if it is a bit illogical that the field wouldn't fire a change event when it has clearly been changed, focus or no).

Comment: However, the `change` event still doesn't fire when you defocus the field. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[This works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/74q7j/) in Chrome 11 and Opera 11.10:

```
<fieldset class="col" oninput="exoutput.value = exnumber.valueAsNumber * exnumber.valueAsNumber;"> 
    <legend>Output event handler</legend> 
    <label for="exnumber">Number: </label> 
    <input type="number" id="exnumber" placeholder="Enter a number" min="0" value="4" required>  
    <label for="exoutput">Output: </label> 
    <output for="exnumber" id="exoutput">16</output> 
</fieldset>
```

Firefox 4 doesn't do valueAsNumber, but [a minor change makes it work in all three](http://jsfiddle.net/74q7j/1/).  Sorry I don't have Safari available to test on right now.