# monitoring type=number?

Tags: jquery, html, input, numbers

I am using the html5 input `type="number"`. I want to monitor this input for change, but:

- because in browsers that support it It gets spin controls I can't just monitor `.keyup`,
- because I don't want to wait for it to lose focus I can't just monitor `.change`.

How can I monitor it so I catch all cases where it's value is changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 event listener for number input scroll - Chrome only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669207/html5-event-listener-for-number-input-scroll-chrome-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at some of the question's on this site and using the [mousewheel plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs) I have got

```
$('#spinbox').bind('click change keyup mousewheel', function() {
  //10 ms timeout is for mousewheel otherwise you get the previous value
  var box = this;
  setTimeout(function() {console.log($(box).val());}, 10);
});
```

So you need to monitor it for

- Click: clicking on the controls
- change: fallback
- keyup: for entering a value
- mousewheel: hmmm... I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

See: [HTML5 number spinbox controls not triggering a change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952267/html5-number-spinbox-controls-not-triggering-a-change-event)

You might use both `oninput` and `onkeydown` for compatibility.